# How to match text in two different file and extract values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, yaml, text-extraction

So I have two files. One yaml file that contains `tibetan words : its meaning`. Another csv file that contains only word and it's POStag. As below:

yaml file :

```
ད་གདོད: ད་གཟོད་དང་དོན་འདྲ།
ད་ཆུ: དངུལ་ཆུ་ཡི་མིང་གཞན།
ད་ཕྲུག: དྭ་ཕྲུག་གི་འབྲི་ཚུལ་གཞན།
ད་བེར: སྒྲིབ་བྱེད་དང་རླུང་འགོག་བྱེད་ཀྱི་གླེགས་བུ་ལེབ་མོའི་མིང་།
ད་མེ་དུམ་མེ: དམ་དུམ་ལ་ལྟོས།
```

csv file :

```
ད་ཆུ PART
ད་གདོད DET
```

Desired output:

```
ད་ཆུ PART དངུལ་ཆུ་ཡི་མིང་གཞན།
ད་གདོད DET ད་གཟོད་དང་དོན་འདྲ།
```

Any idea on how to make text match from csv file to yaml file and extract its meaning in csv?

Comment: Can you provide example output of what the csv file should look like in the end?

Comment: I have updated the question with desired output.

Comment: Read the YAML file and put its content in an object, then read the CSV file and get the words. Use the words to find the meaning using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and then use that info how ever you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your files are called `dict.yml` and `input.csv`.

You can start by turning the yaml file into a dictionary with

```py
import yaml

with open('dict.yaml', 'r') as file:
    trans_dict = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

Which should give you

```py
>>> trans_dict

{'ད་གདོད': 'ད་གཟོད་དང་དོན་འདྲ།',
 'ད་ཆུ': 'དངུལ་ཆུ་ཡི་མིང་གཞན།',
 'ད་ཕྲུག': 'དྭ་ཕྲུག་གི་འབྲི་ཚུལ་གཞན།',
 'ད་བེར': 'སྒྲིབ་བྱེད་དང་རླུང་འགོག་བྱེད་ཀྱི་གླེགས་བུ་ལེབ་མོའི་མིང་།',
 'ད་མེ་དུམ་མེ': 'དམ་དུམ་ལ་ལྟོས།'}
```

Then, you can iterate over the lines in the CSV and use the dictionary to get the definition:

```py
outputs = []
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        term = line.strip()
        definition = trans_dict.get(term.strip())
        outputs.append(
            term if definition is None 
            else f"{term} {definition}"
        )
```

From here, your `outputs` variable should contain `['ད་ཆུ དངུལ་ཆུ་ཡི་མིང་གཞན།', 'ད་གདོད ད་གཟོད་དང་དོན་འདྲ།']`.  If you optionally wanted to write this out to a file, you could do

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(outputs))
```

If you had more tokens on each line of the CSV (unclear from your post), you could iterate over those tokens within a line, but you'd be able to apply basically the same approach.

Comment: I forgot to add one thing in question, the word in csv file contains its POStag and for that i get little stuck. Other wise its working fine. I have update the question, can you have a look

Comment: I am wondering how to strip the POS tag so that I can apply your method

Comment: on the first line after the for loop, you could split the line with something like `word, pos = line.split(' ')[:2]` before then following up with finding the definition and appending to the output var.

Answer (score 4):

On a functional point of view, you have:

- a *dictionary*, meaning here a key: value *thing*
- a *list* of words to search in that *dictionary*, and that will produce a *record*

If everything can fit in memory, you can first read the yaml file to produce a Python dictionary, and then read the *words* file, one line at a time and use the above dictionary to generate the expected line. If the yaml file is too large, you could use the `dbm` (or `shelve`) module as an *on disk dictionary*.

As you have not shown any code, I cannot either... I can just say that you can simply use process the second file as a plain text one and just read it one line at a time. For the first one, you can either look for a `yaml` module from PyPI, or if the syntax is always as simple as the lines you have shown, just process it as text one line at a time and use `split` to extract the key and the value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that came to my mind would be iterating over all lines in the YAML-file and checking if the word is inside the CSV-file:

```
YAML_LINES = "ད་གདོད: ད་གཟོད་དང་དོན་འདྲ།\nད་ཆུ: དངུལ་ཆུ་ཡི་མིང་གཞན\nད་ཕྲུག: དྭ་ཕྲུག་གི་འབྲི་ཚུལ་གཞན\nད་བེར: སྒྲིབ་བྱེད་དང་རླུང་འགོག་བྱེད་ཀྱི་གླེགས་བུ་ལེབ་མོའི་མིང་།\nད་མེ་དུམ་མེ: དམ་དུམ་ལ་ལྟོས།".split("\n")
CSV_LINES = "ད་ཆུ\nད་གདོད".split("\n")


for line in YAML_LINES:
    word, meaning = line.split(": ")

    if word in CSV_LINES:
        output = word + " " + meaning
        print(output)
```

The `YAML_LINES` and `CSV_LINES` lists are only to provide a quick and dirty example.